# Delay interfacing Arduino and Simulink

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-port, simulink

I am trying to read data from **potentionmeter** using an arduino microcontroller (tried both arduino UNO, arduino FIO) and using serial communication interface it to **Simulink** (I tried baud rates ranging from 57600-921600).

Here is the *Arduino* source code:

```cpp
/*
  AnalogReadSerial
  Reads an analog input on pin 0, prints the result to the serial monitor.
*/
#define ana_pin A0 

void setup() {
  analogReference(DEFAULT);
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(ana_pin);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
 // delay(500);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

I interfaced it with **Tera Term software** and there is instantaneous change of values corresponding to 3 V or 0V.

However when I tried to interface it with Simulink model using instrument control toolbox:

[image]

there is a 10 second lag when value changes from ASCII representation of 3V to 0V

[image]

The block **sample time** is `0.01` seconds and the model configuration parameters are adjusted accordingly (I tried it for 1 second or more and the delay still remains. Also, I was able to record data from another sensor and **LPC1768** development board without any delay.

I also tried it with Arduino support libraries in Simulink:

[image]

And it seems that no data is received, as you can see from `Scope1` in the png file the status signal is always `0`. I have also attached hardware implementation properties from Arduino block in Simulink:

[image]

Could you help me understand what is going on and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is the length of lag constant when you change the bitrate?

Comment: In arduino sketch you should try to replace `Serial.print(sensorValue);` with `Serial.println(sensorValue);`; it will add a termination char `\n` (or `\r\n` on windows). Most serial function wait for a special char to know that transmission has ended. In your failing case I think that simulink scopes has a timeout of 10s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As suggested I used Serial.println function and set the terminator in the Instrument control toolbox as <\r\n>. However the 10 sec delay between perceived value changes still persists. Using Serial.println function and setting the terminator in ICT as <none>, the delay increases by  approximately sec (total delay 20 sec). Intuitively its understandable as the delay accounts to reading and displaying the ASCII character for '\r\n'. So I think am pretty sure the delay is due to arduino and simulink interface. Also the length of lag is constant when I change bit rate.

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick Trentin - 
I get a delay of 4 seconds when I use baud rates of 230400, 460800 and 921600.
For baud rate of 57600, 115200 I get a delay of 10 seconds. 
Thank you for pointing it out I did not focus on that previously. 
However since I will be using the sensor in an application which accurately needs reading every 0.01 sec. I dont think I can work with 4 sec delay.